# Component One Report Viewer Find

Tags: silverlight-4.0, reportviewer, componentone

I have a silverlight application which has a Component One Report Viewer in it.  When using the "Find" option from the Toolbar in the Report Viewer, the Text randomly finds text that was not typed.  For instance if I type Commercial into the box, it will highlight text below or in front of the first instance of "Commercial", but never highlights "Commercial".  Does anyone know if there is a bug in the Component One Report Viewer for Silverlight, or if there is a way to set the selected text to equal what is typed in the "Find" box?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
It appears that the issue is when I set the FindText in the ReportViewer, the SelectedText gets set to something else.  How can I set the SelectedText equal to the FindText.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. You should submit it to component one support.

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SupportServices/

http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/silverlight/studio-for-silverlight/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We actually did submit it to Component one not to long after posting and they did acknowledge it as a bug.